# How to load both models to produce a single output in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Ive got an MVC controller named employees, based on an employee table.  One of the employee fields has a foreign key link to an access level table.  Both of these tables are Models in the MVC app (access and employee).

When I create a view to list all the employees, I get this error and it indicates its because it cant reference the accessleveldescription field in the access table/model.

I get the error:
The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

What I'm wanting to know is how do I link the two so I can show the information in a view?

I understand that the AccessLevelDescription is being sought upon population of the view, by which time the DBContext has closed, hence the error,  I'm just not sure how to fix it.

Read several articles, tried adding ToList (but probably set it up wrong), ive tried creating variables to hold the AccessLevelDescription but still cant link the two.

Controller:

```
// GET: Employee
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<accesslevel> AccessList = new List<accesslevel>();
            List<userdetail> EmployeeList = new List<userdetail>();
            using (dbEntities dbModel = new dbEntities())
            {

                EmployeeList = dbModel.userdetails.ToList<userdetail>();
                AccessList = dbModel.accesslevels.ToList<accesslevel>();

            }
            return View(EmployeeList);
        }
```

View:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserEmail)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserPassword)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserCreateDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserLastLogin)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.accesslevel.AccessLevelDescription)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.companydetail.CompanyName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.UserID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.UserID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.UserID })
        </td>
```

Would expect the result to populate the employee information, along with the prescribed accesslevel assigned to the employee.

Answer (score 1):

you should use this one:

```
EmployeeList = dbModel.userdetails.Include(x => x.accesslevels).ToList();
```

instead of:

```
EmployeeList = dbModel.userdetails.ToList<userdetail>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Complementing the answer, if you are using **Lazy Loading** you do not need to use `include`. Just have the `virtual Access` property in `Employee`:

```
public class Employee
{
    public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //This is the FK from Access entitie
    public int AccessId { get; set; }
    //This is the referente to use with the EF Lazy Loading
    public virtual Access Access { get; set; }
}
```

[See more about Lazy Loading.](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/lazyloading-in-entity-framework.aspx)

If you don't want to use Lazy Loading the answer using the include given by hassan.ef is correct.